# Error with program containing multidimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

Got some errors writing this program. Scoured for a while, but I couldn't find anyone with the same problem, with multidimensional arrays.

The purpose if the program is pretty mundane. Make an array, populate it with random ints, display, display even numbers, sort in strange ways. display again.

```
//main.cpp
#include "header.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arrayInt[fd][sd];
    initializeArray(arrayInt[fd][sd]);
}

//functions.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"

using namespace std;

void displayArray(int arrayInt[][sd])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; i++)
        {
            cout << arrayInt[i][j];
        }
        cout << "" << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}

void initializeArray(int arrayInt[][sd])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            arrayInt[i][j] = rand() % 101;
        }
    }
    displayArray(arrayInt[fd][sd]);
    evenArray(arrayInt[fd][sd]);
    sortArray(arrayInt[fd][sd]);
    displayArray(arrayInt[fd][sd]);
}

void sortArray(int arrayInt[][sd])
{
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        for (int j = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            while (arrayInt[i][j] > arrayInt[i][j + 1])
            {
                temp = arrayInt[i][j];
                arrayInt[i][j] = arrayInt[i][j + 1];
                arrayInt[i][j + 1] = temp;
            }
            while (arrayInt[i][j] < arrayInt[i][j - 1])
            {
                temp = arrayInt[i][j];
                arrayInt[i][j] = arrayInt[i][j - 1];
                arrayInt[i][j - 1] = temp;
            }
        }
        if (i % 2 == 1)
        for (int j = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            while (arrayInt[i][j] < arrayInt[i][j + 1])
            {
                temp = arrayInt[i][j];
                arrayInt[i][j] = arrayInt[i][j + 1];
                arrayInt[i][j + 1] = temp;
            }
            while (arrayInt[i][j] > arrayInt[i][j - 1])
            {
                temp = arrayInt[i][j];
                arrayInt[i][j] = arrayInt[i][j - 1];
                arrayInt[i][j - 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    system("pause");
}

void evenArray(int arrayInt[][sd])
{
    int temp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            if (arrayInt[i][j] % 2 == 0)
            {
                temp +=1;
                cout << arrayInt[i][j];
            }
        }
        cout << "" << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}

//header.h
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int fd = 8;
const int sd = 5;

void displayArray(int arrayInt [][sd]);
void initializeArray(int arrayInt [][sd]);
void sortArray(int arrayInt [][sd]);
void evenArray(int arrayInt [][sd]);
```

Errors:

```
error C2664: 'void sortArray(int [][5])' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'int [][5]'functions.cpp

error C2664: 'void initializeArray(int [][5])' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'int [][5]' main.cpp   

error C2664: 'void evenArray(int [][5])' : cannot convert argument 1 from 
'int' to 'int [][5]' functions.cpp
error C2664: 'void displayArray(int [][5])' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'int [][5]'functions.cpp  

error C2664: 'void displayArray(int [][5])' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'int [][5]  'functions.cpp
```

Comment: Look close at your code, it's full of bugs (besides the compiler errors). For example look at the loops in the functions, and what variables are used and what limits you have in the loops.

Comment: `initializeArray(arrayInt[fd][sd]);` here, `arrayInt[fd][sd]` is an int.

Comment: @juanchopanza Not only that, it's an integer from out of bounds as well leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: is something in the text of those errors  *not* self-explanatory?

Comment: Sometimes I just need someone to examine the crap that I write, because I make lots of errors via copy pasting and all that. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass an `array` to a function you must pass only the array name.
`arrayInt[fd][sd]` refers to one element. Also array index starts at 0.  The last element is accessed by

`arrayInt[fd-1][sd-1]`.

So `arrayInt[fd][sd]` leads to overflow.

So change `initializeArray(arrayInt[fd][sd]);`

to

`initializeArray(arrayInt);`

and change other such calls so as to pass only the array name

Comment: Thanks!! I knew I was just an idiot. Happens to me all the time.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
initializeArray(arrayInt[fd][sd]);
```

makes no sense, as `arrayInt[fd][sd]` is of type `int`; call the function as follows.

```
initializeArray(arrayInt);
```